# 画像の2次元配列の組み方を教えてください。

Tags: ios, swift

以下のような感じで配列を作ってViewdidLoad内でUIImageを入れているのですが、これを2次元配列でプログラムするときはどうやって書けばいいんですか

```
@IBOutlet var mainImage: UIImageView!
var imageListArray :Array<UIImage> = []
var number :Int! //前のページから受渡したnumber // 回答者修正

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // UIImage
    let image0:UIImage! = UIImage(named:"img.png")
    let image1:UIImage! = UIImage(named:"img.png") //仮

    // ImageListArray
    imageListArray.append(image0)
    imageListArray.append(image1)

    mainimage.image = imageListArray[number]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swiftには、二次元配列という特別な配列はなく、配列の配列という形で同様のものを実現します。

```
var imageListArray :Array<UIImage> = []
```

これを二次元配列化すると、

```
var imageListArray :Array<Array<UIImage>> = [[UIImage]]()
```

なお、Swiftのシンタックス・シュガーとして、配列の型は`[UIImage]`と記述できますから、

```
var imageListArray :[[UIImage]] = [[UIImage]]()
```

こう書けます。

配列の要素へのアクセスは、

```
imageListArray[2][3]
```

こうなります。C言語と同じです。